# How to copy the cassandra structure to another instance

Tags: cassandra, database-administration

I have to copy the cassandra table structure from Dev to Test environment.

I see we have 98 Keyspace. I dont  need to copy the data and only the structure.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

can do it with cqlsh and a little text editing:

```
echo -e "DESCRIBE SCHEMA;\n" | cqlsh > schema
```

remove the keyspaces you dont want in it (ie system ones)

```
cqlsh -f schema
```